# *Language, Proof, and Logic* Fitch Proof Exercise 6.16

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

This is the last proof I need to finish. I've really been struggling with this one even though it seems so simple. Instructions say use Tarski's world if the sentences are consistent (they aren't), or use Fitch to prove they're inconsistent. Obviously a and b can't be the same size when previously stating that one of the two has to be smaller. Any help would be much appreciated. Says ana con *is* allowed. Problem below..

Premises:

$\operatorname{Smaller}(a, b) \lor \operatorname{Smaller}(b, a),$

$\operatorname{SameSize}(a, b)$

Goal conclusion: $⊥$

Here's a photo of the blank one ,
[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arwWE.png)

Here's what I've done (wrong), [proof2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYEAj.png)

Comment: Do you have any axioms that relate the behavior of the $\text{Smaller}$ and $\text{SameSize}$ predicates to each other? If so, please show them.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean so forgive me if this isn't what you're asking for, but the rules I've learned so far are  ∧,  ∨,  ¬, ⊥ , and = for elim and intro. As well as Ana Con, and briefly Taut Con and FO Con (though I'm not super familiar with those two)

Comment: @HenningMakholm

Comment: x @CCXR: I don't know what "Ana Con", "Taut Con", "FO Con" are, but it sounds like they are deduction rules rather than axioms specific to your predicates. Let me try to ask in a different way: If I claim that you _can't_ prove $\bot$ because the following model satisfies all of your premises, without satisfying $\bot$, then how am I wrong? "The universe is $X=\{a,b\}$, and the interpretation of both $\operatorname{Smaller}$ and $\operatorname{SameSize}$ is the set $X\times X$ (that is, both $\operatorname{Smaller}(x,y)$ and $\operatorname{SameSize}(x,y)$ are true for all $x$ and $y$)".

Comment: @HenningMakholm So you're telling me [Smaller(a, b) ∨ Smaller(b, a)] .. and .. [SameSize(a, b)]  ... can both be true in a single world? I don't understand how that could be possible. Either a has to be smaller than b OR b has to be smaller than a. There's no way they could be the same size, correct? Really new to all of this, excuse my ignorance. Very grateful for the help

Comment: x @CCXR: I suspect you're being confused by the names -- if you don't have any axioms that constrain how $\operatorname{Smaller}$ and $\operatorname{SameSize}$ behave, then they're perfectly free to decide to be true always. They don't know that their names suggest they shouldn't -- logic doesn't care about the _names_ of things, only what the axioms tell you (or don't tell you) about their _behavior_.

Comment: You probably need some axiom schema like this: $\operatorname{Smaller}(a,b)\to[\neg\operatorname{SameSize}(a,b) \land \neg\operatorname{Smaller}(b,a)],$ with a similar one for $\operatorname{SameSize}$.

Comment: Just a note: AnaCon, TautCon, and FO Con are automated theorem provers included with the software that comes with *Language, Proof, and Logic*, by Barwise and Etchemendy. They are tangential for this question.

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{SameSize}(a, b)$ implies $\operatorname{SameSize}(b,a)$

$\operatorname{Smaller}(a, b)$ implies $\lnot \operatorname{SameSize}(a, b)$ 
and $\operatorname{Smaller}(b, a)$ implies $\lnot \operatorname{SameSize}(b, a)$.

Here for the proof [see [LP&L, Ex.6.16, page 164 and page 159](http://homepages.uc.edu/~martinj/Symbolic_Logic/341%20Syllabus,%20Textbook,%20Handouts,%20Notes/LPL%20textbook.pdf)] :

1) $\operatorname{Smaller}(a, b) \lor \operatorname{Smaller}(b,a)$

2) $\operatorname{SameSize}(a, b)$

3) $\operatorname{SameSize}(b, a)$ --- from 2) by Ana Con

--- 4) $\operatorname{Smaller}(a, b)$ --- assumed from 1)

--- 5) $\lnot \operatorname{SameSize}(a, b)$ --- from 4) by Ana Con

--- 6) $\bot$ --- $\bot$-Intro from 2) and 4)

--- 7) $\operatorname{Smaller}(b,a)$ --- assumed from 1)

--- 8) $\lnot \operatorname{SameSize}(b,a)$ --- from 7) by Ana Con

--- 9) $\bot$ --- $\bot$-Intro from 3) and 8)

> 10) $\bot$ --- $\lor$-Elim 1), 4)-6) and 7)-9).

Comment: The text you link to doesn't seem to contain a definition of the "Ana Con" rule everywhere. In step 3 it looks like you're appealing to it to derive $p(b,a)$ from $p(a,b)$. How is that possibly sound?

Comment: @HenningMakholm - see page 60 : "Since the proof system F does not have any rules for atomic predicates other than identity, neither does Fitch. However, Fitch does have a mechanism that, among other things, lets you check for consequences among atomic sentences that involve many of the predicates in the blocks world language. This is a rule we call **Analytic Consequence** or $\text {Ana Con}$ for short. 1/2

Comment: This rule allows you to cite some sentences in support of a claim if any world that makes the cited sentences true also makes the conclusion true, given the meaning of the predicates as used in Tarski's World." 2/2

Comment: But it is easy to construct a world that makes $p(a,b)$ true without making $p(b,a)$ true!`

Comment: The "description" you quote from page 60 uses a lot of words on NOT revealing in any intelligible way what is allowed by the rule.

Comment: See [example](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/17857/logical-consequence-and-tarskis-world).

Comment: x @Mauro: On which grounds do you assert that your rule allows the inference you're trying to make it do? Where are the "rules of the system" you seem to be appealing to? If even you say that you "cannot check it", then it would seem that your claim is purely guesswork, and not actually based on anything in the document you're linking to!